# Where should I store the profile picture obtained from the Microsoft Graph API during a user's session?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, authentication, jinja2, microsoft-graph-api

I am creating a website for an organisation. All of the user details are retrieved from the Microsoft Graph API. The only thing I need help with is that after retrieving the binary for the current user's profile picture, I don't know where I should store the picture. I have figured out how to convert the binary to base64 and display it on the webpage, I just don't know where to place the image. I would prefer not storing it in the database or storing it permanently on the server. I have experimented with storing it in the session token, but that didn't work as the session token was not big enough to store all that data. My website is using Python 3.7.0 and Flask with Jinja2 as the templating system. On the front end, I am using JavaScript and JQuery. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why would you want to store user's personal info in a session, given it's deleted after the session ends?

If it's to be efficient with your API calls, a better solution is to use caching and memoizing.

https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Caching/

If not, I think your best bet is to store it as a BLOB on your filesystem.

[EDIT]:

If you want it to last as long as your session object but can't use for some reason can't use the session object, you can look into setting it as a `_request_ctx_stack` local as such:

```
setattr(_request_ctx_stack.top, 'user_image', user_image)
```

And to fetch it back use:

```
user_image = LocalProxy(lambda: getattr(_request_ctx_stack.top, 'user_image'))
```

now you can import it from wherever the `user_image` variable is defined

Comment: Thanks for responding. I wanted to store it in the session because all I need it for is to have be displayed once the user logs in. After the user logs out, I don't need it anymore. I'm not too worried about retrieving it again if the user logs in again as I am not retrieving a high resolution copy of the image. I'll have a look into Flask Caching, thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: No problem, check my updated answer and see if that fits you better

Comment: Worked great! Had to change a couple things. I used  _app_ctx_stack instead and I setattr _app_ctx_stack, not _app_ctx_stack.top. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @CharmingRobot, how can you delete the user's img after the session ends? I'm using sessions but when downloading the img, I had to use a static/temp folder and the img doesn't delete after the session ends.